# Value of 'a' for which $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^2}{2} +ax+b $ is injective

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^2}{2} +ax+b   \forall   x \in R$.
Find the least value of *a* for which $f(x)$ is injective function.

My approach , for $f(x)$ to be injective either f(x) should be increasing or decreasing function.'

$Y=f'(x)=x^2+x+a$ [Increasing function]

If $Y>0$, then $x^2+x+a>0$, it is possible when $1-4a<0$ or $a>\frac{1}{4}$

If $Y<0$, then $x^2+x+a<0$, it is possible when $1-4a \ge 0$ or $a \le \frac{1}{4}$

The options are **(A) $\frac{1}{4}$** which is the correct option, the other given options are (B) $1$, (C) $\frac{1}{2}$, (D) $\frac{1}{8}$

Though my optin is correct but i have one doubt when the equality=$0$, then Y=$0$ hence it is neither increasing nor decreasing function.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of computing $f'$ is fine, but your computation is wrong. In fact$$f'(x)=x^2+x+a=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+a-\frac14.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I thought of it but i want to check it for both increasing and decreasing option, for increasing option can we take $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x) \ge 0$

Comment: If you always have $f'(x)\geqslant0$ and if the equality $f'(x)=0$ only holds finitely many times, then $f$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want $f$ is injective, then $f$ should be increasing since leading part is $x^3$. So $f'(x)=x^2+x+a\geq 0$ for all $x$, so the discriminant $D\leq 0$ and that is iff $1-4a\leq 0$ so $a\geq {1\over 4}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you need $f^\prime$ to be non-negative for **all** $x$.